# Vim-like multiline handling in Sublime Text 2

Tags: vim, sublime-text-2

```
The quick brown fox
ate the lazy dog.
```

In vim, if my cursor is at `n` in `brown`, and I execute `d/lazy`, I'll erase everything from brown to lazy.  If I do `c/lazy`, similarly I'll do all this while jumping into insert mode.

With Sublime Text 2 (incl. Vintage Ex), this doesn't work.  The `d` and `c` commands are ignored after `/` brings up a search box.  (the search, however, is performed).

Is there any way around this or an alternative?

Comment: This limitation as already been discussed here and on SO. I don't think there's a solution. The alternative is to use Vim

Comment: No, I don't think there is. As much as they like to boast (and ST2 is a really nice text editor) we've still to wait for one that really has all vim key functions.